# One function for multiple "plus" and "minus" buttons that create and delete inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input, append, removechild

Hi I'm trying to make a "plus" button that when clicked create an input and a "minus" button that when clicked deletes the last input.
Because I want to use the same function to do the same thing with multiple "lines", I tried to add the name of the variable "count" in the parameter of the function. This is what seems to make the snippet bug but I can't figure out how to make it work.

```js
let count1 = 0;
let count2 = 0;
function newX(x, y){
    y++;
    let inputsContainer = document.getElementById(x);
    let newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "text"; newInput.id = x+y;
    inputsContainer.appendChild(newInput);
}
function deleteX(x, y){
    document.getElementById(x).lastChild.remove();
    y--;
}
function result(){
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = document.getElementById('AAA-').innerHTML + document.getElementById('BBB-').innerHTML
}
```

```html
<h2>Test 1</h2>
<div style="display : flex;">
  <div>
    <button onclick="newX('AAA-', count1)">+</button>
    <button onclick="deleteX('AAA-', count1)" style="margin-right:5px;">-</button>
  </div>
  <div id="AAA-">
    <input type="text" id="AAA-0">
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
<div style="display : flex;">
  <div>
    <button onclick="newX('BBB-', count2)">+</button>
    <button onclick="deleteX('BBB-', count2)" style="margin-right:5px;">-</button>
  </div>
  <div id="BBB-">
    <input type="text" id="BBB-0">
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Name of the new ids</h2>
<button onclick=result()>Show</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :

```js
function newX(x){
      var div = document.getElementById(x);
      var inputs = div.querySelectorAll("input");
      let numInputs = inputs.length;
    let inputsContainer = document.getElementById(x);
    let newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "text"; newInput.id = x+numInputs;
    inputsContainer.appendChild(newInput);
}
function deleteX(x){
    document.getElementById(x).lastChild.remove();
}
function result(){
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = document.getElementById('AAA-').innerHTML + document.getElementById('BBB-').innerHTML
}
```

```html
<h2>Test 1</h2>
<div style="display : flex;">
  <div>
    <button onclick="newX('AAA-')">+</button>
    <button onclick="deleteX('AAA-')" style="margin-right:5px;">-</button>
  </div>
  <div id="AAA-">
    <input type="text" id="AAA-0">
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
<div style="display : flex;">
  <div>
    <button onclick="newX('BBB-')">+</button>
    <button onclick="deleteX('BBB-')" style="margin-right:5px;">-</button>
  </div>
  <div id="BBB-">
    <input type="text" id="BBB-0">
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Name of the new ids</h2>
<button onclick=result()>Show</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you made is your function to create the elements that has the same id while creating the new input. You can remove the last element by using `parentDom.lastchild.remove()`. Please check my code.

```
function deleteX(x, y){
    let lastInputName = x+y;
    let lastInput = document.getElementById(lastInputName);
    document.getElementById(x).lastChild.remove();
    y--;
}
```

Comment: It's not the same id because I add the value of y (aka the counter) after the id :), but I agree for the second advice (.lastChild.remove()) it's easier

Comment: it's the same id because you didn't define the variable ```y``` outside of the function. And then if my solution is helped you, could you kindly check my answer?

Comment: the parameter y is equal to "count1" or "count2" which is defined outside the function. So my problem is still there, because the first time I press "plus" the new input is called AAA-1 but after the second click, the next input's id is still AAA-1 (instead of AAA-2). I've edited my snippet so It's easier to understand the problem.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QZfHhl4.png    This is the result when I run your project on codepen.

Comment: ```but I agree for the second advice (.lastChild.remove()) it's easier ```. If so, I think my solution help you absolutely. I think you can check my answer

Comment: -->i.imgur.com/QZfHhl4.png = exactly what I explained, the first = AAA-0, the second = AAA-1, but the third = AAA-1 too instead of AAA-2

Comment: it's because you define y in the function.

Comment: yeah but I don't know how to do differently :(

Comment: I think it's better to use my solution in this case. I was trying to follow your code, it needs more code and logic for count... Please upvote my article if my solution helped you.